# Difference between sending object and sending pointer to object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, segue

Whats the Difference between:

```
NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem: object];
```

**and**

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:_objects[indexPath.row]];
```

_objects is NSMutableArray

Thanks,

Comment: The two above are exactly the same and may in fact generate the same code.  You always refer to Objective-C objects by pointer -- you never "send" a physical copy of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference, both send the parameter as pointer to an object -- this is always the case passing objects as parameters in iOS.

The only difference is in the first example, the expression was assigning it to a local variable first to give it a name.

Comment: Please add some clarity to your answer, like providing some links, adding examples, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you're sending an instance of an NSDate object, assuming that is what is stored in your array. The two implementations are virtually identical.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in Objective C are allocated on the heap and therefore are accessed through a pointer. Objective C doesn't have the concept of stack objects like C++ and other languages do.